# PySimpleGUIでplt.figureを行うとウィンドウが縮小されてしまう

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

PySimpleGUI使用中にmatplotlib.pyplotでfigureオブジェクトを作成すると，PySimpleGUIで作成したアプリケーションのウィンドウサイズが固定縮小してしまうのですが，これを回避する方法はありますか．

**実行環境**
Python 3.10.2
matplotlib 3.5.1
PySimpleGUI 4.57.0
Windows 11 Home (21H2)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz   1.50 GHz

**ソースコード**

```py
import PySimpleGUI as pg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

layout = [
    [pg.Button(key='-button-',button_text='         ')]
]

window = pg.Window('demo', layout,size=(800,600))


while True:
    event, _ = window.read()

    if event == None:
        break
    if event == '-button-':
        plt.figure()
```

Comment: Linux では再現しませんでした。動作環境も記載したほうがよいかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます．質問を編集しております．

Comment: Windowsでも提示されたソースコードで問題が再現しませんでした。PCのDisplay環境・設定などといった別の要因かもしれません。元々のやりたい事も含めてこちらの記事が参考になるかも。[PySimpleGUIにMatplotlibを埋め込みたい](https://qiita.com/bear_montblanc/items/cce4e8c58dfa236200f6) とその中の [ウィンドウの解像度が荒い問題](https://qiita.com/bear_montblanc/items/cce4e8c58dfa236200f6#%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E5%83%8F%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%8C%E8%8D%92%E3%81%84%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C)

Comment: ありがとうございます．結局原因が分からず仕舞いでしたが，お教えいただいたリンク先の通りにCanvasを用いると改善致しました．

Answer (score 1):

他サイトに類似の質問があったため，ここで共有させて頂きます．

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4561

Comment: もしリンク先の情報で解決したようであれば、ポイントとなる部分を引用して回答に含めておくと、より分かりやすくなるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: DPIを合わせるというのが解のようですが、どうも危なっかしいので、PySimpleGUIを使う部分とmatplotlibを使う部分は別プロセスにした方が安全かも知れません。

Comment: 皆さまありがとうございます．特にリンク先の情報で解決したわけではありませんが，リンク先の質問者様は解決されていたようなので一応共有させて頂きました．結局Canvasを用いてMatplotlibと紐づけるという方法でこの問題を解決しました．https://qiita.com/Gyutan/items/e753700011439057156f#3-canvas%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95